Blender Out of System GPU Memory, but only sometimes in the same scene
I am rendering a big scene with lots of textures and meshes, so it's taking up a lot of memory. I am getting frequent out-of-memory errors while rendering, but sometimes Blender is rendering hundreds of frames non-stop without any out-of-memory errors. The same frame that showed an out-of-memory error got rendered smoothly without any modifications.
I am rendering on a GPU RTX 2050 4GB using OptiX, as CUDA is very slow.

I got it to work. Basically I had to reduce meshes and textures by a lot such that GPU has almost 500-600 mb memory left during render. For persistent data, reduce the threads to half and now it's working.
